# How to merge all the testng emailable report into single report through programatically

Tags: java, testng, testng-eclipse

I have 100 test cases and retry logic will execute if there are any failed test scripts and the emailable report had only status of failed test scripts alone. I just want to merge the first and retry run test reports as single one in the form of emailable report in testng after execution completed. Probably in Jenkins post build activity I just want to perform merge activity. I just need suggestions, and efficient way to achieve this.

**Screenshot:**

[image]
The above screenshot had 3 emailable.html report. I just want to create another emailable report which has the consolidate details of all three html files.

Answer (score 0):

Same answer for this as well :)

As HTML is basically an XML. We can merge it with xlst. Using xpath, we can easily isolate which section had to extracted from each html and merge them to single html
Refer this post for better idea.[Merging html files using XSLT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48397222/merging-html-files-using-xslt)

Comment: Can you please share me some sample code base to extract certain piece of code from each html file and merge it with one

Comment: Refer this example https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-tipcombxslt/index.html

Comment: Also refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16865911/merge-multiple-xml-files-at-group-levels-with-xslt. Use xslt 2.0 version for more functionality.

Comment: Many thanks for sharing the source. Let me go through this.